# Как проверить поле на заполненность?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Имеется форма, нужно проверить ее на заполненность полей.
Кнопка отправки блокируется пока не будут заполнены все поля.

Но после того как я ввожу текст в поле, она все равно остается неактивной.
Подозреваю это из-за того что `$(document).ready(function ()`

Как при этом изменить на `change`, скажем, не пойму.
И через функцию пробовал `onkeyup="check();`, тоже не совсем понятная логика получается (проект не я писал, поэтому пока не могу объяснить почему)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.btn-reg').addClass('disabled-btn');
  var fio = $('.pickup_cdek #order_order_address_attributes_city').val();

  if(fio.length != '') {
    $('.btn-reg').removeClass('disabled-btn');
  } else {
    $('.btn-reg').click(function(){
    
    if($('.btn-reg').hasClass('disabled-btn')){
      // подсвечиваем незаполненные поля и форму не отправляем, если есть незаполненные поля
      $('.pickup_cdek #order_order_address_attributes_city').addClass('empty');
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.pickup_cdek').find('.require').removeClass('empty');
      },1500);
        return false
      } else {
        // Все хорошо, все заполнено, отправляем форму
        return true
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.disabled-btn {cursor: default !important;background: #b3b3b3}
.empty {border-color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<tr>
  <td class="ltd">
  <label for="order_order_address_attributes_city">Город <i>*</i></label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="pickup_cdek">
      <div class="ui-widget" style="z-index: 1; top: 104.438px; left: 137.734px; display: block;">
        <input class="ent-inp require" id="order_order_address_attributes_city" name="order[order_address_attributes][city]" > 
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>

<div class="reg-f"><table><tbody><tr class="reg-col"><td class="ltd">&nbsp;</td><td><input class="btn-reg disabled-btn" name="commit" type="submit" value="Подтвердить"></td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var fio = $('.pickup_cdek #order_order_address_attributes_city');
$('html').on('keyup keydown change', fio, function(){
    if(fio.val().length != '') $('.btn-reg').removeClass('disabled-btn');
    else  $('.btn-reg').addClass('disabled-btn');
})
```

Comment: Стоит отметить что проверки на JS бред, лучшей поверкой будет проверка на стороне бэкэнда .
а для вашей цели можно сделать форму и полям добавить атрибут required

Comment: не стоит такого отмечать, ибо это не соответствует действительности. Предварительная проверка отправляемых данных на стороне клиента это хорошо, это позволяет снизить нагрузку на сервер. Однако, это конечно же не снимает ответственности за проверку данных на стороне сервера.

Comment: Для этого есть html https://habrahabr.ru/post/313250/
Зачем изобретать велосипед на js

Comment: очевидно, приведенные вами проверки, могут помочь сделать валидацию лишь самых простых случаев. Для проверки на пустоту,конечно, удобно и стоит применять. Но без полноценной валидации формы на js вы никуда не денетесь при работе с более сложным контентом.

Comment: Просветите меня, чего тут не хватает?
http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/pattern

Comment: Единственное что я бы интегрировал на js, это маску телефона, для красоты.

Comment: вы можете выйти за рамки примитивных полей? поля могут быть связными, а логика заполнения форм достаточно сложной. Повторюсь, с помощью стандартной валидации можно решить лишь самые простые случаи. Проверка по регуляркам это тоже самый простой случай, ибо там нет логики, проверил на соответствие и все. Никуда вы от js не денетесь в итоге.

Answer (score 0):

> Просто замените на свои поля и добавьте сколько Вам нужно новых!

```js
(function($) {

  $(function() {

    $('.rf').each(function() {
      var form = $(this),
        btn = form.find('.btn_submit');
      form.find('.rfield').addClass('empty_field');

      function checkInput() {
        form.find('.rfield').each(function() {
          if ($(this).val() != '') {
            $(this).removeClass('empty_field');
          } else {
            $(this).addClass('empty_field');
          }
        });
      }

      function lightEmpty() {
        form.find('.empty_field').css({
          'border-color': '#d8512d'
        });

        setTimeout(function() {
          form.find('.empty_field').removeAttr('style');
        }, 500);
      }

      setInterval(function() {

        checkInput();

        var sizeEmpty = form.find('.empty_field').size();

        if (sizeEmpty > 0) {
          if (btn.hasClass('disabled')) {
            return false
          } else {
            btn.addClass('disabled')
          }
        } else {
          btn.removeClass('disabled')
        }
      }, 500);

      btn.click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {

          lightEmpty();
          return false
        } else {

          form.submit();
        }
      });
    });
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.form_box {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

.form_box label {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #444444;
  display: block;
}

.form_box input {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #444444;
  padding: 7px 7px 8px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.form_box input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #07a6e6;
}

.form_box .btn_submit {
  border: none;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #07a6e6;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 0;
}

.form_box .btn_submit:hover {
  background: #009ac2;
}

.form_box .btn_submit:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.form_box .btn_submit.disabled,
.form_box .btn_submit.disabled:hover {
  background: #afdde6;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form_box">
  <form action="#" method="post" class="rf">

    <label for="user_town">Город:</label>
    <input type="text" class="rfield" id="user_town" />

    <label for="user_adress">Адресс</label>
    <input type="text" class="rfield" id="user_adress" />

    <input type="submit" class="btn_submit disabled" value="Отправить данные" />

  </form>
</div>
```